# Why OpenGL provided with latest GeForce drivers is so extremely slow?

Tags: opengl, performance, nvidia

I'm writting a code in OpenGL and using two computers - an old and a new one.

On the old computer (which I use for debugging/creating implementation for the old GL) I have GeForce 5500 FX. Before windows reinstall on it, I had NVIDIA drivers with OpenGL 1.5. And **everything worked perfectly**. Games made quite good FPS, even with dozens or hundreds sprites.

However, after XP reinstall, I installed the drivers provided with my video card but it seems there's no OpenGL at all (mysterious 'GDI Generic' renderer). So I tried to download the newest NVidia drivers. **After their installation** I saw there's **OpenGL 2.3** but when I runned my app it worked with **extremely low FPS** (about 0.25, I mean I had to wait four seconds for any app reaction) with only **one sprite**. And as I loaded smaller images, the FPS relatively increased, but on the new computer it's always (no matter how big and how many sprites) speed, so it must be the perfomance problem. Without any sprites, it seemed it worked normal, but game without graphics doesn't make any sense.

That's why I downloaded the oldest drivers for NVIDIA GeForce 5500 FX I found on the Nvidia site. But they're still providing OpenGL > 2.0 (2.1 exactly). The problem's the same.

I also tried to change all the properties of OpenGL to increase performance but it didn't help too.

So what can I do? **I'd like to find drivers with OpenGL 1.5** but it seems they're not on the NVIDIA site and most people say it's the best to download they from there.